# Custom Scrollbars in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, scrollbar

I've been looking into implementing custom scrollbars into ExtJS. I've tried the ExtJS Scrollpane port found here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?86071-Ext.ux.ScrollPane, as well as trying to use jQuery along with ExtJS like shown here: [Changing scroll-bars in ExtJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263040/changing-scroll-bars-in-extjs).

I haven't been able to get it working though and was wondering if there is anyone has experience getting custom scrollbars into Ext JS that can lead me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to update on my situation. I've managed to get jScrollPane([link]http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) to change my scrollbars using:  `$(function(){
                        $('.x-grid-view').jScrollPane();
                    });`

in FireBug. However, when I try to call it in the render, afterrender, or afterlayout listeners it doesn't work. Any ideas on where I should be calling the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't apply the

```
$(function(){ $('.x-grid-view').jScrollPane(); });
```

in the render or afterrender listeners. At that point the store of the grid has not loaded yet. You have to put this code where the store has already loaded the data.

The reason why in firebug you could make it work is because at the time the store is already loaded.

Btw, I got this working in Extjs 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here's an example**](http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2011/11/extjs-and-iscroll-scrolling-ext-containers-on-touch-devices-ipad-iphone-etc-using-iscro) of someone who got iScroll integrated with ExtJS. It includes code samples and a working demo.

Comment: This looks to be exactly what I'm looking for. Going to start looking into it now. Thanks so much! Will update with progress.

Comment: Ah wait nevermind, the iScroll seems to be very touch oriented and does not behave like a normal scrollbar on a desktop? Or is there a way to set up iScroll such that it behaves like a normal scrollbar?

Comment: Absolutely, I am not that familiar with it but it has almost as many configs as ExtJS does.

Comment: @Kuma I should rephrase that, it has almost as much configs as an ExtJS panel.

Comment: After multiple attempts at trying to implement this, it seems that this is broken as of Ext JS 4.x. I think the API for Ext JS has changed since this was originally done. Does anyone else know of ways to theme the scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

you can try FleXcroll or jsscroll bar work well with Ext js